# How to mix Vue components with HTML outside the template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Think about a wordpress blog, or a standard CMS with some content. I use a wysiwyg editor (CKEditor) to write my contents and save them to db.

I want to use some Vue components inside this HTML, and so I add a wrapper div to my theme. HTML pages are wrapped by

```
<div id="#my-custom-app">
...html from server
</div>
```

Basically I want to add for example

```
<my-app-image-compare></my-app-image-compare>
```

using CKEditor inside my HTML, then I will create an app mounted on #my-custom-app div. I will insert the app at the end of the html body.

Vue.app file doesn't have a template, the template is basically my HTML page written with CKEditor, but every component is loaded and defined by the app and every component has a template.

How can I do? Is there a way to have a main Vue app file without a defined template?

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1:

First create a vue container on a basic template. This template will then load a component which gets your data from the sever and displays it, so:

```
// This is your main vue instance container
<div id="#my-custom-app">
  <dynamic-html v-if="myHtmlFromServer" template="myHtmlFromServer"></dynamic-html>
</div>
```

Within this main component, you need to hook up created event and populate `myHtmlFromServer` with your HTML content from the editor.

```
import DynamicHtml from './myComponents/DynamicHtml'
new Vue({
  el: '#my-custom-app',
  data () {
    return {
      myHtmlFromServer: ''
    }
  },
  components: {
    DynamicHtml
  }
  created () {
    // this.myHtmlFromServer = this.getDataFromServer()
  }
})
```

The `<dynamic-html>` component, would have `props: ['template']` and on the created event would assign `this.$options.template = this.template`.

This option will set the HTML template of that component and allow Vue to render it as normal (meaning you can then do `{{someVal}}` in your CKEditor.

### Option 2:

Another option is if you're using a server side language like PHP, then you could just put that html on the page i.e `echo $myHtmlContent` and as long as that content contains `<div id="#my-custom-app">` you Vue instance will mount. PHP will add the HTML to the page *before* the JS processes the page so it'll just work.

Comment: Is the option 2. But you assume that <div id="#my-custom-app"> is inside the html rendered with echo $myHtmlContent, my case is different. I want to wrap the echo $myHtmlContent with the #my-custom-app div and use the components inside the HTML rendered from the server